# How should I interpret irregular lag correlation in time series?

Tags: time-series, arima

I'm not sure how to interpret the autocorrelation pattern I'm seeing in this time series and any help would be very appreciated. Below is the ACF plot for my data. To me this looks like seasonal nonstationary but I'm a beginner so I can't be sure.

[image]

The PACF is where I'm more confused. How should I interpret the declining correlation followed by the spike at lag 5? The literature I've read doesn't seem to help.

[image]

Here are the ACF and PACF plots of the first differences:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the lag 5 have meaning for your data? Does your data have some similarity 5 measurements ago? Are you familiar with seasonality?

Comment: @user2974951 I am familiar with seasonality. I have no idea why the 5th lag would be so meaningful. Would this still be seasonality if the preceding lag isn't statistically significant?

Comment: It's hard to tell, it could be something, it could be nothing. From ACF and PACF you can conclude that your series is not stationary and that there may be some periodicity / seasonality. Try adding some AR or MA terms and see what happens.

Comment: @user2974951 Unit root test does conclude nonstationarity. If I try to minimize AIC I get an ARIMA (4,1,2).

Comment: Have you tried seasonal terms also? Anyway, if ACF and PACF plots look good now then you should be good.

Comment: @user2974951 Yes I included some seasonal terms, but for some reason it doesn't affect the AIC

Comment: In any case, if your selected model shows no more autocorrelation and seasonal terms do not help then you are done.

Comment: @user2974951 Thank you.